# How to write time series (multiple data points per time) to csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I'm trying to loop through a given timeframe and create a csv file of times, altitude, and u and v winds. The problem I'm running into is that each time has multiple values of altitude, u, and v. The data should basically have this structure:

| Time | altitude | u wind | v wind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | 1000 | 10.1 | 13.5 |
| 1200 | 2000 | 15.3 | 24.8 |
| 1200 | 3000 | 22.7 | 33.1 |
| 1300 | 1000 | 12.2 | 15.6 |
| 1300 | 2000 | 18.9 | 24.9 |
| 1300 | 3000 | 34.6 | 36.2 |

But I think what my loop is making is something like this, thus the lengths not matching:

| Time | altitude | u wind | v wind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | 1000 | 10.1 | 13.5 |
| 1300 | 2000 | 15.3 | 24.8 |
|  | 3000 | 22.7 | 33.1 |
|  | 1000 | 12.2 | 15.6 |
|  | 2000 | 18.9 | 24.9 |
|  | 3000 | 34.6 | 36.2 |

I tried this loop, but got this error:
ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (83).

```
def main():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('radar_id', help="The 4-character identifier for the radar (e.g. KTLX, KFWS, etc.)")
    ap.add_argument('-m', '--storm-motion', dest='storm_motion', help="Storm motion vector. It takes one of two forms. The first is either 'BRM' for the Bunkers right mover vector, or 'BLM' for the Bunkers left mover vector. The second is the form DDD/SS, where DDD is the direction the storm is coming from, and SS is the speed in knots (e.g. 240/25).", default='right-mover')
    ap.add_argument('-s', '--sfc-wind', dest='sfc_wind', help="Surface wind vector. It takes the form DDD/SS, where DDD is the direction the storm is coming from, and SS is the speed in knots (e.g. 240/25).")
    ap.add_argument('-t', '--start-time', dest='start_time', help="Start time to plot. Takes the form DD/HHMM, where DD is the day, HH is the hour, and MM is the minute.")
    ap.add_argument('-e', '--end-time', dest='end_time', help="End time to plot. Takes the form DD/HHMM, where DD is the day, HH is the hour, and MM is the minute.")
    ap.add_argument('-f', '--img-name', dest='img_name', help="Name of the file produced.")
    ap.add_argument('-p', '--local-path', dest='local_path', help="Path to local data. If not given, download from the Internet.")
    ap.add_argument('-c', '--cache-path', dest='cache_path', help="Path to local cache. Data downloaded from the Internet will be cached here.")
    ap.add_argument('-w', '--web-mode', dest='web', action='store_true')
    ap.add_argument('-x', '--fixed-frame', dest='fixed', action='store_true')
    args = ap.parse_args()

    np.seterr(all='ignore')
    
    start_time = args.start_time
    end_time = args.end_time
    loop_time = start_time
    minute = timedelta(minutes=1)
    
    tmp2 = pd.DataFrame()
    dates = []
    
    while loop_time <= end_time:
        try:
            vad_plotter(args.radar_id,
                        storm_motion=args.storm_motion,
                        sfc_wind=args.sfc_wind,
                        time=loop_time,
                        fname=args.img_name,
                        local_path=args.local_path,
                        cache_path=args.cache_path,
                        web=args.web,
                        fixed=args.fixed
                        )
            tmp = tmp.append(params, loop_time)
            tmp2 = tmp2.append(data['altitude'], u, v, loop_time)
            date_time = datetime.strptime(loop_time, '%Y-%m-%d/%H%M')
            dates.append(date_time)
            
        except:
            if args.web:
                print(json.dumps({'error':'error'}))
            else:
                print('This time does not exist. Continuing to next time.')
        loop_time_dt = datetime.strptime(loop_time, '%Y-%m-%d/%H%M')
        loop_time_dt += minute
        loop_time = datetime.strftime(loop_time_dt, '%Y-%m-%d/%H%M')
    
    tmp2.insert(0, 'Time', dates)
    tmp2.to_csv('uvwinds.csv')
```

Sorry if this question is confusing. I struggled with how to word it.

Comment: Could you explicitly define what are the types of data['altitude'], u and v? Where do they come from? Are them lists? In such that case what is the expected length of each of them?